# How to stop one process and go to next process in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a script to download consecutive satellite and radar images as they come online, later combine them into satellite image animation and radar image animation. I created two separate scripts to download images from satellite and radar. I run these from the shell script same time.

```
python ./rad/rad_retrieval.py; python ./sat/sat_retrieval.py
```

Satellite and radar images updated online every 30 min, so these 2 python scripts will download images every 30 min until we stop the process. Part 2, has the code to combine each satellite and radar image into animation/movie with ImageMagick.

```
# Part 1
echo starting...
python ./rad/rad_retrieval.py; python ./sat/sat_retrieval.py

# Part 2
#combining downloaded satellite images into video
cd /home/Cast/sat_retrieved
echo saving video for satellite images
convert -delay 50 20210516-*.jpg Satellite_retrieved.mp4
echo saving video : Success

#combining downloaded radar images into video 
cp Satellite_retrieved.mp4 /home/Cast/
cd /home/Cast/Radar_retrieved/
echo saving video for radar
convert -delay 50 20210516-*.gif Radar_retrieved.mp4
echo saving video : Success
```

This is my script, I want to stop part 1 after a while with user input and go to part 2 without stopping the entire shell script. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore SIGTERM and set a handler for SIGINT to kill children upon its arrival in the parent shell. This way the user can simply hit Ctrl-C and skip the first part.

```
# first part
python ./rad/rad_retrieval.py &
python ./sat/sat_retrieval.py &
trap '' term
trap 'kill 0' int
wait
trap - term int
# second part
```